# How to make parent and child processes listen to each other?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm trying to simulate CPU and memory in C using only fork and pipe. I have the CPU as a parent process and the memory as a child process. I want the CPU to communicate with the memory when it needs to fetch a new instruction and also when it needs to write to memory. How can I have the memory listen to the CPU and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement in IPC mechanism (IPC=inter process communication). Depending on what your OS provides, you can choose among several mechanisms: message queues, shared memory, sockets and so on.

For example, if you choose an implementation of a message queues based IPC on Linux, you can check this: https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview .